Working Around Large Dataset that gives me 413 Error
I'm working on a project where I'm attempting to use Sheets API to grab the data from a large set of data. It's about 400K rows with 11 columns. I have seen methods where people split the load into batches of 100K rows at a time but I'm at a loss at how I would do this while performing some cleanup. I have have to loop through the rows to remove any rows where one of the columns equals 1 of 36 values. Here is a sample of a script that I attempted but I get stuck at the dataSourceArr gathering of data as that is the sheet that contains the large dataset.
  //Data from Content Column. These are the excluded items
  excludedContentArr = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(tss.getId(), `'` + excludedContentSht.getName() + `'!A2:A`).values;  
  
  //This is the large dataset that is giving me an error right now
  dataSourceArr = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(sourceSS.getId(), `'` + dataSourceSht.getName() + `'!A1:` + columnToLetter(dataSourceSht.getLastColumn())).values;
  var headersDataSrcArr = dataSourceArr[0];//Get the first and only inner array
  var eidDataSrcCN = headersDataSrcArr.indexOf('EID') + 1;//Arrays are zero indexed- add 1.
  var contentDataSrcCN = headersDataSrcArr.indexOf('Content') + 1;//Arrays are zero indexed- add 1.
  var statusDataSrcCN = headersDataSrcArr.indexOf('Status') + 1;//Arrays are zero indexed- add 1.
  var compDateDataSrcCN = headersDataSrcArr.indexOf('Completion Date') + 1;//Arrays are zero indexed- add 1.
  var pathwayDataSrcCN = headersDataSrcArr.indexOf('Pathway') + 1;//Arrays are zero indexed- add 1.
  
  var values = [];
  for(var i in dataSourceArr){    
    var excludedContentIndex = excludedContentArr.map(r => r[0]).indexOf(dataSourceArr[i][contentDataSrcCN-1]);
    if(excludedContentIndex == -1){
      //Action if not found
      values.push([
        dataSourceArr[i][eidDataSrcCN-1],
        dataSourceArr[i][contentDataSrcCN-1],
        dataSourceArr[i][statusDataSrcCN-1],
        dataSourceArr[i][compDateDataSrcCN-1],
        dataSourceArr[i][pathwayDataSrcCN-1]
      ]);

    }
  }
  Logger.log('Found ' + values.length + ' rows of data that met the criteria.');

  //Paste into the destination sheet.
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.update({ values }, tss.getId(), `'` + pathwayContentCompSht.getName() + `'!A2`, { valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED" });


You can see where I am looping to exclude any rows that contain any of the excluded content. Example of data to be excluded:



Content




Back to the Future 1


Back to the Future 2


Back to the Future 3



Example of Large Dataset:



EID
Content
Status
Completion Date
Pathway




a1
Rocky 5
Complete
01/01/2024
abc123


a2
Back to the Future 1
Complete
01/01/2024
abc123


a3
Rocky 4
Complete
01/01/2024
abc123


a4
Rocky 3
Complete
01/01/2024
abc123


a5
Back to the Future 2
Complete
01/01/2024
abc123


a6
Rocky 2
Complete
01/01/2024
abc123


a7
Rocky 1
Complete
01/01/2024
abc123


a8
Matrix Revolutions
Complete
01/01/2024
abc123


a9
Back to the Future 3
Complete
01/01/2024
abc123


a10
Matrix
Complete
01/01/2024
abc123



Example of End Result:



EID
Content
Status
Completion Date
Pathway




a1
Rocky 5
Complete
01/01/2024
abc123


a3
Rocky 4
Complete
01/01/2024
abc123


a4
Rocky 3
Complete
01/01/2024
abc123


a6
Rocky 2
Complete
01/01/2024
abc123


a7
Rocky 1
Complete
01/01/2024
abc123


a8
Matrix Revolutions
Complete
01/01/2024
abc123


a10
Matrix
Complete
01/01/2024
abc123




I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand loop through the rows to remove any rows where one of the columns equals 1 of 36 values. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the simple sample input and output situations you expect? And also, can you provide the error message of 413 Error? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

I updated my question to include examples of what the data looks like and what it should look like for the end result. The error message is HttpResponseException: Response Code: 413. Message: response too large.

Thank you for replying. From your reply and updated question, I have 4 more questions. 1. About HttpResponseException: Response Code: 413. Message: response too large., where the line does this error occur in your showing script? 2. Where are the values Content from? 3. Where are the values Example of Large Dataset from? 4. Where do you want to put the result value Example of End Result?

The error occurs on the second line with dataSourceArr = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(...

The values for Content are coming from a sheet excludedContentSht. I grab those values on the first row. The Large dataset is coming from an external sheet and it is what is generating the error from my pervious response to you with dataSourceArr. The end result will be placed on the pathwayContentCompSht as I am trying to do on the very last line of code I included.

Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between your showing script and your provided tables. In your script, "EID" and "Pathway" are used. But, in your tables, those columns are not found. Also, in your script, it seems that you want to put values from row 2 of the destination sheet. It seems that values has the 1st header row. Is this your expected result? In your script, all scripts except for the line of dataSourceArr = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(,,,) work fine. Is my understanding correct?

Although, unfortunately, I have several questions for correctly understanding your question and I do not know your actual situation, I proposed a modified script as an answer by my guess. Please confirm it. But, if this modified script was not useful, I apologize. At that time, I'm worried that it might be required to test your situation.

You're right about EID and Pathway. In the table I used ID and Message instead. I corrected that. As for the headers, I am clearing the whole destination sheet except for the headers so values does not need to include the header. I will pull headers another way than trying to get it from values. Originally I thought I would pull it all into values, including headers, and then search for the position of the columns and then after doing the work I needed to do I would dump all but the header. I will try your solution and get back to you. Thanks.

From your following reply,

The error message is HttpResponseException: Response Code: 413. Message: response too large.


The error occurs on the second line with dataSourceArr = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(...

I understand that your error of HttpResponseException: Response Code: 413. Message: response too large. occurs at dataSourceArr = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(sourceSS.getId(), '+ dataSourceSht.getName() +'!A1: + columnToLetter(dataSourceSht.getLastColumn())).values;. If your other parts except for this work fine, how about the following modification?
In this modification, the values are retrieved and put by separating rows.
Modified script:
Before you use this script, please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services.
// ref: https://tanaikech.github.io/2022/04/25/report-handling-10000000-cells-in-google-spreadsheet-using-google-apps-script/
function getValues_({ spreadsheetId, sheetName, start = 1, maxRow, limit = 100000 }) {
  return [...Array(Math.ceil(maxRow / limit))].flatMap((_) => {
    const last = start - 1 + limit;
    const range = `'${sheetName}'!A${start}:${last > maxRow ? maxRow : last}`;
    const temp = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(spreadsheetId, range).values;
    start += limit;
    return temp;
  });
}

// ref: https://tanaikech.github.io/2022/04/25/report-handling-10000000-cells-in-google-spreadsheet-using-google-apps-script/
function setValues_({ spreadsheetId, sheetName, start = 1, maxRow, limit = 100000, values }) {
  Array.from(Array(Math.ceil(maxRow / limit))).forEach((_) => {
    const v = values.splice(0, limit);
    Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.update({ values: v }, spreadsheetId, `'${sheetName}'!A${start}`, { valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED" });
    start += limit;
  });
}

function myFunction() {
  // Please set your variables.
  var tss = 
  var excludedContentSht = 
  var sourceSS = 
  var dataSourceSht = 
  var pathwayContentCompSht = 



  // --- I modified the below script.
  excludedContentArr = getValues_({ spreadsheetId: tss.getId(), sheetName: excludedContentSht.getName(), start: 2, maxRow: excludedContentSht.getLastRow(), limit: 100000 });
  dataSourceArr = getValues_({ spreadsheetId: sourceSS.getId(), sheetName: dataSourceSht.getName(), start: 1, maxRow: dataSourceSht.getLastRow(), limit: 100000 });
  // ---


  var headersDataSrcArr = dataSourceArr[0];//Get the first and only inner array
  var eidDataSrcCN = headersDataSrcArr.indexOf('EID') + 1;//Arrays are zero indexed- add 1.
  var contentDataSrcCN = headersDataSrcArr.indexOf('Content') + 1;//Arrays are zero indexed- add 1.
  var statusDataSrcCN = headersDataSrcArr.indexOf('Status') + 1;//Arrays are zero indexed- add 1.
  var compDateDataSrcCN = headersDataSrcArr.indexOf('Completion Date') + 1;//Arrays are zero indexed- add 1.
  var pathwayDataSrcCN = headersDataSrcArr.indexOf('Pathway') + 1;//Arrays are zero indexed- add 1.

  var values = [];
  for (var i in dataSourceArr) {
    var excludedContentIndex = excludedContentArr.map(r => r[0]).indexOf(dataSourceArr[i][contentDataSrcCN - 1]);
    if (excludedContentIndex == -1) {
      //Action if not found
      values.push([
        dataSourceArr[i][eidDataSrcCN - 1],
        dataSourceArr[i][contentDataSrcCN - 1],
        dataSourceArr[i][statusDataSrcCN - 1],
        dataSourceArr[i][compDateDataSrcCN - 1],
        dataSourceArr[i][pathwayDataSrcCN - 1]
      ]);

    }
  }
  Logger.log('Found ' + values.length + ' rows of data that met the criteria.');


  // --- I modified the below script.
  setValues_({ spreadsheetId: tss.getId(), sheetName: pathwayContentCompSht.getName(), start: 2, maxRow: values.length, limit: 100000, values });
  // ---
}


This worked great! 24 seconds to copy and 1:33 to paste. One thing I will note though for anyone using this script... you need to make sure you have the correct number of rows available in the destination sheet. I got an error stating that only 100K new lines could be added at a time. Once I added the new rows manually it was no problem.

Quick question for you. I need to remove duplicates. Would you recommend I attempt to delete them in the array or on the sheet after pasting, using removeduplicates(). Duplicates are determined by columns EID & Content

@DanCue Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

@DanCue About your additional question I need to remove duplicates. Would you recommend I attempt to delete them in the array or on the sheet after pasting, using removeduplicates(). Duplicates are determined by columns EID & Content, although I'm not sure about your actual situation, in the case of removeDuplicates, the duplicated rows can be removed by an argument including columns. Ref I guess that this might be able to be used.
